# Не запускается IntelliJ IDEA x64

Tags: intellij-idea

При первом запуске появляется окно самого запуска, исчезает через секунды 2 и все, в процессах не отображается, при повторном запуске окно уже даже не появляется, раньше работало прекрасно, спустя время - такая херня. Переустанавливал уже много раз, менял значения в vmoptions. ОЗУ у меня 16 гб, проблем как бы быть не должно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему при помощи программы Reg Organizer (не реклама), она удалила программу вместе с файлами в реестре и тд.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled Intellije, removed these 2 folders Roaming\JetBrains & Local\JetBrains, reinstalled IntelliJ, and it works.

Windows:

- Configuration (idea.config.path):
  C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
- Plugins (idea.plugins.path):
  C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins
- System (idea.system.path):
  C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
- Logs (idea.log.path):
  C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\log

Comment: здесь пишут на русском языке